# How to send only the variable value through the url in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to send **only the value of the variable** through the URL as following examples,

`https://twitter.com/johndoe`

```
https://www.facebook.com/johndoe/
```

And I don't want it to be like `https://twitter.com/?name=johndoe`

Thank you!

Comment: this is what's called a mod rewrite in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Use mod rewrite to rewrite url